# why python is returning none after calculation?

Tags: python

I want to have a tool that outputs me a multiplication table.
so I writhe this:

```
def multiplicationTable(number):
    for x in range(1, 11):
        result = number * x
        print(f'{number} X {x} = {result}')

result = multiplicationTable(5)
print(result)
```

This returned me a multiplication table as expected but followed by an extra `None` type value.

```
5 X 1 = 5
5 X 2 = 10
5 X 3 = 15
5 X 4 = 20
5 X 5 = 25
5 X 6 = 30
5 X 7 = 35
5 X 8 = 40
5 X 9 = 45
5 X 10 = 50
None
```

why is that happening.

Comment: You don't tell it to `return` something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiplicationTable(number)` has no return value.

By default, when no `return` value is given, a python function will return `None` to signify that it was successfully executed. You have the same behavior in other languages.

To illustrate this, I made your function return something at the end :

```
def multiplicationTable(number):
    for x in range(1, 11):
        result = number * x
        print(f'{number} X {x} = {result}')
    return 'I have finished'

result = multiplicationTable(5)
print(result)
```

Output :

```
5 X 1 = 5
5 X 2 = 10
5 X 3 = 15
5 X 4 = 20
5 X 5 = 25
5 X 6 = 30
5 X 7 = 35
5 X 8 = 40
5 X 9 = 45
5 X 10 = 50
I have finished
```